# Certificate chain processed, but terminated in XP's Outlook Express

Tags: windows-xp, gmail, smtp, ssl-certificate, outlook-express

I know someone with Windows XP (SP3) who **suddenly** can no longer send messages in Gmail via Outlook Express without answering "yes" to the following message:

[image]

There is no problem whatsoever receiving messages (via IMAP), only sending them. Everything is defined according to https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229

Any idea how to fix this? Perhaps an unsupported way to update XP's root certificates?

Comment: Some google properties recently switched to certs under Google IA 3 (instead of 2) which is under a GlobalSign root (instead of GeoTrust with optional bridge to Equifax) and the one XP system I still have does not have that particular GlobalSign root. But the machines _I_ get for imap&smtp.gmail.com = 209.85.232.109 and 173.194.68.108 don't do this, nor the ones sslshoper.com/ssl-checker gets = 173.194.205.109 and 74.125.29.108 . OTOH if this is the problem for 'somebody', then adding a root to XP certstore/TrustedRoots is certainly supported. ...

Comment: ... If you or they can connect with `openssl s_client` or java `keytool -printcert -sslserver` from the affected location (ISP) you can see exactly what cert chain you are getting. `s_client` allows you to exclude SNI, as I believe XP schannel always (including OE) does, in case that matters. OTOH I don't believe the Shining Light build of OpenSSL still supports XP since it's 2 years past EOL, so you may have to find another (or conceivably build your own).